# Is it okay to return void to a TapGestureRecogniser initiated method?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have this XAML for Button.xaml :

```
<Frame xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
                  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
                  xmlns:t="clr-namespace:Japanese.Templates" 
                  xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Japanese;assembly=Japanese" 
                  x:Class="Japanese.Templates.Button" x:Name="this" 
                  VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                  HeightRequest="{DynamicResource GridButtonHeight}" >
<Frame.GestureRecognizers>
    <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding TapCommand, Source={x:Reference this}}" 
                          CommandParameter="{Binding ., Source={x:Reference this}}" />
    <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="ChangeTheColours" />
</Frame.GestureRecognizers>
<Label Text="{Binding Text, Source={x:Reference this}}" x:Name="ButtonLabel" />
</Frame>
```

and this C# in my application for Button.xaml.cs

```
    private async void ChangeTheColours(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (this.ButtonLabel.Text != null && (string)this.ButtonLabel.Text.Substring(0, 1) != " ")
            {
                ConfigureColors((Button)sender, "C");
                await Task.Delay(200);
                ConfigureColors((Button)sender, State);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Crashes.TrackError(ex,
                new Dictionary<string, string> {
                        {"ChangeTheColours", "Exception"},
                        {"Device Model", DeviceInfo.Model },
                });
        }
    }
```

For this example, is it okay to return void for the async method or is there a requirement that I should return a Task?

Comment: If you want to add a Task in your method, you should absolutely make your method as async. You don't need to make the whole method being a task one unless you want it to be run on another thread.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since this is an event it cannot be converted into a `Task`.

When you check the [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/classes#events):

> An event is a member that enables an object or class to provide notifications. Clients can attach executable code for events by supplying event handlers.
>
> Events are declared using event_declarations

And when you read the last statement it says:

> Each accessor corresponds to a method with a single value parameter of the event type, a void return type, and the same modifiers as the containing event.

Comment: So is it's still okay that I have it as async returning void as I wanted to be able to have an await in there?

Comment: Yes in case of events it is okay as it is a restriction that you cannot change it, I hope it makes more sense now